# Why does the order of the replace-command matter when I swap a class with JavaScript in the following case?

Tags: javascript, css, class, replace, getelementsbyclassname

I swap the colour of two containers by swapping their classes. For this I use a button which invokes the function *swap()*.

Everything works fine as long as I swap the class of the green container first. But when I reverse the order and start with the green button the colors don't swap but remain as they are (see comment in my source code below).

I would appreciate if someone could help me to understand this behaviour. Since I store both elements in two different variables (greenElement and redElement) I expected that I do not have to keep a certain order.

**Why does the order matter?**

```js
function swap(){
var greenElement = document.getElementsByClassName("greenClass");
var redElement = document.getElementsByClassName("redClass");

redElement[0].classList.replace("redClass", "greenClass");
greenElement[0].classList.replace("greenClass", "redClass");

// IN THIS ORDER IT DOESN'T WORK
// greenElement[0].classList.replace("greenClass", "redClass");
// redElement[0].classList.replace("redClass", "greenClass");
}
```

```css
.greenClass{
background:green;
}

.redClass{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="greenClass">green</div>
<div class="redClass">red</div>
<button type="button" onclick="swap()">click</button>
```

As you see in the comment the order in which I replace the classes matters.

Comment: The clue is that `getElementsByClassName()` returns a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) that gets updated when underlying document changes. When you swap classes you move element from one collection to the other

Comment: thank you very much, charlietfl!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @charlietfl explained, `getElementsByClassName` returns a live collection.

Let's take the first approach,

1. Your HTML initially looks like this,

```html
<div class="greenClass">green</div>
<div class="redClass">red</div>
```

2. Now, when the following statement is executed,

```js
var greenElement = document.getElementsByClassName("greenClass");
var redElement = document.getElementsByClassName("redClass");
```

```
<div class="greenClass">green</div> // Represents greenElement[0]
<div class="redClass">red</div> // Represents redElement[0]
```

3. After this statement is executed,

```
redElement[0].classList.replace("redClass", "greenClass");
```

```
<div class="greenClass">green</div> // Represents greenElement[0]
<div class="greenClass">red</div> // Represents greenElement[1]
```

Notice, how the two arrays `greenElement` and `redElement` have updated live such that `greenElement` has now 2 elements whereas `redElement` has 0.

4. After this statement is executed,

```
greenElement[0].classList.replace("greenClass", "redClass");
```

```
<div class="redClass">green</div> // Represents redElement[0]
<div class="greenClass">red</div> // Represents greenElement[0]
```

Now, let's see the second approach,

1. Your HTML initially looks like this,

```
<div class="greenClass">green</div>
<div class="redClass">red</div>
```

2. Now, when the following statement is executed,

```
var greenElement = document.getElementsByClassName("greenClass");
var redElement = document.getElementsByClassName("redClass");
```

```
<div class="greenClass">green</div> // Represents greenElement[0]
<div class="redClass">red</div> // Represents redElement[0]
```

3. After this statement is executed,

```
greenElement[0].classList.replace("greenClass", "redClass");
```

```
<div class="redClass">green</div> // Represents redElement[0]
<div class="redClass">red</div> // Represents redElement[1]
```

Notice, how the two array `greenElement` and `redElements` have updated live such that `greenElement` has now 0 elements whereas `redElement` has 2.

4. After this statement is executed,

```
redElement[0].classList.replace("redClass", "greenClass");
```

```
<div class="greenClass">green</div> // Represents greenElement[0]
<div class="redClass">red</div> // Represents redElement[1]
```

Hope, this helps you to understand.

Comment: Definetly very helpful and well explained! Thank you very much, you made my day.

Comment: Happy to help.. :)